# SpringBoot Security - Unauthorized URL

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this SpringBoot security configuration:

```
  @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(publicMatchers()).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/book/list")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll();
        }

 private String[] publicMatchers() {

         /** Public URLs. */
        final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
                "/webjars/**",
                serverContextPath + "/css/**",
                serverContextPath + "/js/**",
                serverContextPath + "/fonts/**",
                serverContextPath + "/images/**",                
                "/api/**",
                serverContextPath ,
                "/",
                "/error/**/*",
                "/console/**",
                ForgotMyPasswordController.FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL_MAPPING,
                ForgotMyPasswordController.CHANGE_PASSWORD_PATH,
                SignupController.SIGNUP_URL_MAPPING
        };

        return PUBLIC_MATCHERS;

    }
```

expecting that this URL http://localhost:5678/pradera/api/users/fcm (with PUT method), will be public, but when I test it on Postman, Ii redirects me to the login page

on publicMatchers() method I have also  `"/api/**",` and it seems to work for the call http://localhost:5678/pradera/api/deviceevent/list (GET)

Comment: You have a /pradera mapping before /api mapping, but in your security configuration only /api is matched for permitAll() change it to /pradera/api/** to make it work unless you haven't provided context mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this:  `http.csrf().disable();`